# How to put files into Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, vmware

I did an internship and they used vagrant so all the developers whould run the same latest version of the web application.
But now i want to create my own vagrant webserver.
I got to the point that i setup vagrant using the hashicorp/precise32 box.
I got nginx running on my own special ip adress that i changed in the hosts file.
So now i can go to mytestsite.com and it will show me welcome to nginx.

But now my question is, how can i get my own file(small test web application) into the vagrant server because i do not know how to transfer my files to vagrant.
And how can i let my friends use my vagrant test web application.

Thank you for your help!

Sincerely Mex
19 years old
web application student in the Netherlands

Answer (score 0):

By default vagrant will have a synced folder between your vm and the host machine. It is in the same folder as the vagrantfile and can accessed through `/vagrant` on your host machine.

However if you want more customization and mount certain folders on your host machine and sync them to the vagrant VM it can be done in the vagrant file as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # other config here

  config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/srv/website"
end
```

Here is a quick guide to get you started using vagrants [synced folders](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) and the example i posted

Comment: Thank you very much, i will look into it!

Comment: do i change it to what it says right there, or do i change the last name into my own website name.

Comment: `src/` is the path on your host machine and `/srv/website` is the path in which the folder should be mounted in your vagrant VM.

Comment: Hi thank you again for your help. I did as you said but when i reload or do vagrant up i get an error.::   Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The shared folder guest path must be absolute: srv/website
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: src/
i did it as you said: config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/srv/website"